# Integer i=3 vs Integer i= new Integer (3)

Tags: java

I am comparing 2 pieces of code. First

```
Integer i=3;
Integer j=3;
if(i==j)
   System.out.println("i==j");  //prints i==j
```

Second,

```
Integer i=3;
Integer j=new Integer(3);
if(i==j)
   System.out.println("i==j"); // does not print
```

I have doubt that in the first snippet why `i==j` is being printed? Shouldn't the references be different?

Comment: Something to do with refernece, new, Objects, compairing memory addresses #Idk #CIS20...Somthing

Comment: `==` compare references not values, when you assign. In fist case both `i`, `j` points to same integers in memory. where in second case using new you create two new instance of object integer with same value 3.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. Notice that question was closed as a "not a real question" due to a mistaken premise that `new Integer(1) == new Integer(1)`, which isn't true.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - It's the same question, just inverted, which the answer to that question covers.

Comment: It's *not* the same question. Jon Skeet posted a similar answer but the question is quite different!

Comment: @JohnKugelman: Agreed, although it amuses me that my answer in the linked question *does* answer this question... but not as well (IMO) as my answer in this one :)

Comment: @AMR: No, that is not the case at all.

Answer (score 18):

It's to do with how boxing works. From the [JLS section 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

Basically, a Java implementation *must* cache the boxed representations for suitably small values, and *may* cache more. The `==` operator is just comparing references, so it's specifically detecting whether the two variables refer to the same object. In the second code snippet they definitely won't, as `new Integer(3)` definitely isn't the same reference as any previously created one... it always creates a new object.

Due to the rules above, this code must always give the same result:

```
Integer x = 127;
Integer y = 127;
System.out.println(x == y); // Guarantee to print true
```

Whereas this could go either way:

```
Integer x = 128;
Integer y = 128;
System.out.println(x == y); // Might print true, might print false
```

Comment: You should explain == comparison.

Comment: @William Morrison: Disagree. The OP clearly already gets that `==` is reference equality. The issue is that he mistakenly expects the references to be different (that is, the missing concept here is "interning" for some primitives, not not grokking `==`).

Comment: I'm not messing with anyone. Perhaps I'm mistaken.  I prefer excessively thorough explainations...

Comment: @WilliamMorrison: Is the edited answer better? I included `==` behaviour at the same time as explaining that `new Integer(3)` would definitely create a new object. (Despite the other comments, I have no problem with including some extra explanation here...)

Comment: @WilliamMorrison So, according to you, every explanation should start with: "In the beginning, there was the word ..."

Comment: Yes I really like this answer now, great job.

Comment: Very interesting that the pooling is defined in the JLS specification, given that for Integer's case, it's done via the Integer class and not the JVM.

Comment: If Jon Skeet answer you question you only have to say thank you, because surely is correct, don't say "You should ..." lol

Answer (score 6):

Java pools integers between -128 and 127 and hence both the references are the same.

```
Integer i=3;
Integer j=3;
```

This results in autoboxing and 3 is converted to Integer 3. So for i is referring to an Integer object that is in constant pool, now when you do j=3, the same reference as that of i is assigned to j.

Whereas below code:

```
Integer j=new Integer(3);
```

always results in a new Integer creation, in heap. This is not pooled. And hence you see that both reference are referring to different objects. Which results in

```
Integer i=3;
Integer j=new Integer(3);
if(i==j)
   System.out.println("i==j"); // **does not print**
```

Comment: ... in the first case.

Answer (score 3):

> I have doubt that in the first snippet why i==j is being printed?
>   Shouldn't the references be different?

Because,

```
    Integer i=3;
    Integer j=3;
```

are internally using [Integer#valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) to perform `autoBoxing` . And oracle doc says about `valueOf()` method that:

> Returns an Integer instance representing the specified int value. If a
>   new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be
>   used in preference to the constructor Integer(int), as this method is
>   likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by
>   caching frequently requested values. **This method will always cache
>   values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values
>   outside of this range.**

Since the value `3` is cached therefore, both variables `i` and `j` are referencing the same object. So, `i==j` is returning `true`. `Integer#valueOf()` uses [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Answer (score 3):

```
Integer i=3;
Integer j=3;
if(i==j)System.out.println("i==j");
```

Here, `3` is being auto-boxed and hence `i` and `j` point to the same `Integer`.

```
Integer i=3;
Integer j=new Integer(3);
if(i==j)System.out.println("i==j"); // does not print
```

Here, `i` points to the auto-boxed `Integer` whereas `j` points to a new `Integer` and hence there references fail the equals `==` operator test.

But, here's some more food for thought.

```
Integer i=300;
Integer j=300;
if(i!=j)System.out.println("i!=j"); // prints i!=j
```

Why? Because, auto-boxing shares `Integer` instances between -128 to 127 only. This behaviour, however, may differ between different Java implementations.

Comment: `Integer`'s pooling is not done by the JVM. It's entirely done by `Integer`. See `Integer`'s source code.

Comment: @SteveKuo I just checked `Integer.valueOf()` and yes the range is bounded by `Integer` between -128 to `IntegerCache.high` (127). I've corrected my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No they shouldn't, because java can use pre-fabricated Integer objects for small numbers when autoboxing.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second peice of code your first integer is being auto-boxed while the second is not.

This means a new Integer instance is being created on the fly.  These 2 object instances are different.  The equality check will return false there as the two instances are actually different pieces of memory.

Comment: No, it's the *first* piece of code which is using autoboxing in both cases; the second uses it only for the first value.

Comment: I was referring to the first integer, not the second.

Comment: That was extremely unclear. It's *still* unclear from this answer why the first piece of code prints "i==j", because you haven't explained anything about the caching nature of boxing.

Comment: Yes it was unclear I suppose.  And I agree about neglecting to explain auto-boxing adequately. Yours is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreter/JIT optimizer can put all 3's in same box. But if you force a "new" then you get another address.

Try

```
 j=8; // after initialization of i and j
```

then see the j's address changed for first version.

Answer (score 0):

In a *similar* fashion to strings, when autoboxing is used, such as in

```
Integer i = 3;
Integer j = 3;
```

Java can draw from a pool of prefabricated objects. In the case of `j`, there's already an `Integer` instance representing the value of `3` in the pool, so it draws from that. Thus, `i` and `j` point to the same thing, thus `i == j`.

In your second example, you're explicitly instantiating a new `Integer` object for `j`, so `i` and `j` point to different objects, thus `i != j`.

Answer (score 0):

In Following Piece of Code:

```
Integer i=3;
Integer j=3;
if(i==j)
   System.out.println("i==j");
```

Here, "==" compares reference with each other rather than the value.
So, Integer i and j both are referring to same reference in the memory.

while in Following Piece of Code:

```
Integer i=3;
Integer j=new Integer(3);
if(i==j)
   System.out.println("i==j");
```

The reference to both values are changed because 'j' is newly created object/reference of Integer in memory while 'i' is just referring to a value.

Therefore, the output of 1st code is "i==j" and 2nd code does not have any output.

Hope this helps.